# Security PATCH SUPEE-10975 Installation error in Config.xml

Tags: magento-1.9, installation, supee-10975

I have the same flaw. I have all the previous patches set except for php 7.0. Returning to the "original" version of config.xml has not solved the problem. How can I solve it?

Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...

ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

```
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Group/Edit.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Newsletter/Template/Edit.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/BlockController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Customer/GroupController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/SitemapController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/BackupController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/Model/Observer.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/Model/Zend.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Api2/Product/Image/Rest/Admin/V1.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Media/Api.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Images/Storage.php
Hunk #2 succeeded at 387 (offset -1 lines).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 28.
1 out of 3 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/sql/core_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.6.1.2-1.6.0.6.1.3.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Container/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Customer.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 280 (offset -9 lines).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Customer/Address.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 281 (offset -22 lines).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Payment/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Payment/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Payment/sql/payment_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.0.1.1-1.6.0.0.1.2.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sendfriend/Block/Send.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/controllers/IndexController.php
patching file app/code/core/Zend/Controller/Request/Http.php
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/cms/browser/content/files.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/captcha.xml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/sharing.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/sendfriend/send.phtml
patching file app/etc/modules/Mage_All.xml
patching file app/etc/modules/Mage_Captcha.xml
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Wishlist.csv
patching file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.js
patching file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js
patching file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.min.map
patching file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.1.js
patching file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.1.min.js
patching file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.1.min.map
```

Comment: What is the exact magento version you are using?

Comment: 1.9.2.4  with the patch  SUPEE-10888_CE